# Javascript: Filter JSON by date - display past and future objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json

What I want to achieve is, to filter the JSON by past and future events from the current date - like now. My "past" API route should display only the past events, like `"id":1` for this example.

Can I do that with, let's say, `momentjs` and `lodash`? What would be a correct approach?

**This is my JSON array containing the `datetime` timestamp.**

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "datetime": "2017-08-18T15:15:00+0200",
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "datetime": "2020-03-31T10:30:00+0200",
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "datetime": "2020-03-31T10:30:00+0200",
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [**Date.parse()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) method to parse string dates and compare it with current time and `filter` accordingly as follows:

---

```js
const data = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "datetime": "2017-08-18T15:15:00+0200",
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "datetime": "2020-03-31T10:30:00+0200",
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "datetime": "2020-03-31T10:30:00+0200",
    }
];

const pastDates = data.filter(x => Date.parse(x.datetime) < new Date());

const futureDates = data.filter(x => Date.parse(x.datetime) > new Date());

console.log("Past dates", JSON.stringify(pastDates, null, 4));

console.log("Future dates", JSON.stringify(futureDates, null, 4));
```

Comment: Thank you very much and sorry, I didn't notice that this question has already been answered. Linked the original question.